# Collection name error while importing Json to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, mongoexport

As I was importing a new json file to my mongodb collection I've accidentally use just one '-' instead of 2. Eg.:

```
mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1 --db=dataBaseName -collection=people --file=importFile.json
```

I believe that due to the lack of the second '-', now I'm stuck with the following results when I type show collections:

```
people
ollection=people
```

I can't access, drop or interact with the second one. Apart from droping the database and starting over, is there a way around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the collection like:

```
> use YourDatabase
// Might wanna drop people collection first
> db.getCollection("ollection=people").renameCollection("people")
```

Hope This helps!

Comment: It sure did. Thx